# Error "Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document" when trying to select option of drodown

Tags: python, selenium, select, drop-down-menu

```
select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[4]/form/div/select"))
options = len(self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[4]/form/div/select/option"))
m = 1
while m <= options:
    value = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[4]/form/div/select/option["+str(m)+"]").get_attribute("value")
    text = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[4]/form/div/select/option["+str(m)+"]").text
    select.select_by_value(value)

    m = m + 1
```

When running the Code i get the following error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
> (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.71)

The HTML Code is the following:

```
<div class="select-field">
    <select name="group[14]" data-ajax-select-variants="true">
        <option selected="selected" value="211">
            1 Jahr                             
        </option>
        <option value="209">
            3 Jahre                             
        </option>
        <option value="348">
            5 Jahre                            
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

As it is now, it select's the first two options without any Problems, but when it tries to select the third option it gives me the above shown error.

I tried:

1. Selecting the option via "select_by_visible_text"
2. getting the options of the dropdown via Select().options
3. for loop with Select().options
4. Selecting the options via "select_by_index"
5. Before selecting the new option deseleccting all

Comment: Share the URL. If not possible share the HTML code.

Comment: And also share the complete error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message:
> stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
> (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.71)

Indicates that a reference to an element is now "stale" --- the element no longer appears on the DOM of the page. The reason for this expectation is may be your `DOM` got updated or refreshed. For an example, after performing an action like `click()` your `DOM` may get updated or refreshed. In this time when you are trying to find an element on `DOM` you will experience this error.

You have to re-find that element in updated or refreshed `DOM`

```
 try:  
        element1 = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.xpath, "/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[4]/form/div/select/option["+str(m)+"]"))
        value = element1.get_attribute("value")
        element2 = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.xpath, "/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[4]/form/div/select/option["+str(m)+"]"))
        text = element2.text
        select.select_by_value(value)  
 except StaleElementReferenceException:
        element1 = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.xpath, "/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[4]/form/div/select/option["+str(m)+"]"))
        value = element1.get_attribute("value")
        element2 = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.xpath, "/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[4]/form/div/select/option["+str(m)+"]"))
        text = element2.text
```

The `xPath` are what you are using are not reliable. It may fail in future if there is any change in `DOM` structure.

Comment: Sadly i can not use this Code because this Syntax is no longer supported in Python 3.9. Do you maybe have a Updated Version?

Comment: Can you see now..Updated

Comment: @nadan-a Sadly this does not work for me :( I get the same error message: _selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.71)_

Comment: Added explicit wait. Can you please try now

Comment: In case if it is throwing element is not visible exception then change `visibility_of_element_located` to `presence_of_element_located` and try again

Comment: I left an upvote for question :)

Comment: Glad it helped :)